# Using matlab to manipulate each element in a vector without a for loop

Tags: matlab, vector, vectorization

I'm trying to write some code in matlab that will manipulate each element in a vector and will also return a vector.  So basically if I have a vector x = [1 2 3 4 5]'; I would like to perform 2 * x(i) * i, where i is the ith element in the vector.  And return y = [2 8 18 32 50]';

Right now I have the code:

```
N = length(x);
for i=1:N
    y(i,:) = (i*2).*x(i,:);
end
```

I've new to Matlab so I've been doing research to try and learn the syntax that will let me do element by element multiplication and all that but it's been difficult.  I can't get past that 1:numel(x) takes the place of my i.  Again I'm new to matlab so any explanation on the answers that will help me learn is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: A side note, it is best [not to use `i` as a variable name in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

```
y = x.*(1:numel(x))*2
```

Here is why: Often we want to do an operation to every element in a vector or matrix. Matlab will allow you to do this with **element-wise** operations. For example, suppose you want to multiply each entry in vector `x` with its corresponding entry in vector `y`. In other words, `x(1)*y(1)`, `x(2)*y(2)`,etc. in order to do this, one should use the symbol `.` before the multiplication. In fact, you can put a `.` in front of any math symbol to tell Matlab that you want the operation to take place on each element of the vector or matrix.